# Unable to copy vhdx file (Hyper-v)

Tags: hyper-v

(Windows 10 Pro)

I am unable to copy and paste a vhdx file from my current drive (1TB Samsung NVME) to my new drive (2TB Samsung NVME).

I have tried:

- Copy/Paste Windows explorer
- Robobopy
- 'Move' command in Hyper-V Manager
- 'Export' command in Hyper-V Manager
- Powershell (administrator) use Export-VM command
- NVME clone using a piece of hardware that should clone NVME cards - it can do this without being connected to a PC - as it has its own power supply. Can be bought off Amazon fairly cheap.

The error message I get when trying to export my VM (called PythonDev) to my bigger drive is:

[image]

If I try and copy and paste I get the following error (but is still the same underlying problem I think). I have narrowed it down to actually copy the vhdx file - nothing I can do will allow me to copy that file:

[image]

Here is the Powershell error:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked the drive for errors?  This is probably caused by a file system error which might be hardware related.  What is the S.M.A.R.T status of the drive?  What does `chkdsk` tell you?

Comment: Yes - done all these checks - all virtual drives and the actual drive itself - clean as a whistle!

Comment: The errors you received suggest the file doesn’t actually exist on the file system. If that’s the case there isn’t anything you can do since the file no longer exists on the drive

Comment: @Ramhound - but what on earth could it be, its like one big file - what can the file be thats missing inside it. Is it even inspecting whats inside the vhdx - or should their be an associated file with it? It any case I have done nothing to it that would lead it to having a missing file.